# PHP check existance of negative index not working?

Tags: php, arrays, isset, array-key-exists

I have some code that runs fine until it hits this:

```
if(array_key_exists($snIdx, $fields));
    $surnameField = trim($fields[$snIdx]);
```

or other version I tried:

```
if(isset($fields[$snIdx));
    $surnameField = trim($fields[$snIdx]);
```

The `$snIdx = -1`.
It gives me Undefined offset error at second line (`$surname = trim...`).
I think I don't need to paste rest of code as the exception says there is sth wrong with those functions. My PHP version is 5.4.16.

Comment: Well, do you have `$fields[-1]`?

Comment: No I don't. That's why the exception is thrown. But that's why there is a condition.

Comment: Your condition does nothing, since you have `;` at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I guess I have to go outside for a while to reset my brain.

Comment: Yeah, it happens, go relax for a while :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the `if` line. Otherwise it's equivalent to:

```
if( something) {
    // no-op
}
$surnameField = trim($fields[$snIdx]); // undefined offset error.
```

Comment: Ahah:D +1 Shame on me.

Comment: I am ashamed that it took me four whole minutes to answer this question :p